Boy is electrocuted by a guitar and travels to the past
The movie plot is that a school boy gets electrocuted by his electric guitar and travels back in time. There is a scene in the movie where he uses his polaroid camera to click a picture and the people at the king's court think he has stolen their soul. Can you please identify this movie?

Sounds like the Canadian movie A Young Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court  with Michael York and Theresa Russell from 1996:

In this live-action adaptation of Mark Twain's fantasy-adventure, a contemporary teenager fixing a friend's electric guitar accidentally gets transported through time to King Arthur's Camelot.

After traveling back in time, the protagonist escapes a death sentence after being accused of capturing a knight's soul with his Polaroid camera. The entire movie is currently available on Youtube.


Yup that's the one..thank you very much!!
